# Java Class.forName cannot find class

Tags: java, classloader, java-security

I have a class in my application:

```
package com.myapp;

public class Foo {}
```

When I try to load it like this:

```
package com.myapp;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Class.forName("com.myapp.Foo");
    }
}
```

It works.
However, if I try to use classloader from `AccessController`, it throws `ClassNotFoundException`:

```
package com.myapp;

public class Main {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
         final ClassLoader classLoader = AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivilegedAction<ClassLoader>() {
             public ClassLoader run() {
                  return Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
             }
         });
         Class.forName("com.myapp.Foo", true, classloader);
    }
}
```

Full stacktrace is the following:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.myapp.Foo
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at com.myapp.Main(Main.java:10)
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Could you add information about JDK you are using?

Comment: I am using JDK 8

Comment: These code work fine in my environment, show more code?

Comment: Seems you have to add the class `com.myapp.Foo` on the boot class path. Since you custom class loader is from main thread class loader which is null.

Comment: I tried Oracle JDK 1.8.0_201 and it works fine without any error (although the code will have to be modified to solve compilation issues). So, more code would help. Also, the error might be caused simply by stale .class files (this will be ruled out if you clean and rebuild all sources).